# Can't select between radio buttons in HTML?

Tags: html

I have the following form code but I cannot select the sell radio in IE
and I can select both radios at once in Google Chrome.

```
<form method="post" action="dothemath.php" style="width: 403px" class="style1">
<input type="radio" id="rdobuy" style="width: 20px; height: 21px;" checked="checked"/>
<label>Buy</label>
<input type="radio" id="rdosell" style="width: 20px; height: 21px;"/>
<label >Sell</label>
</form>
```

Is there any thing I am missing...?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your radio buttons don't have `name` attribute. They need them for two reasons.

1. Having the same name groups a set of radio buttons into a single radio group
2. The name is used to generate the form data to be submitted to the server

You also need a `value` to say what the submitted data is going to be.

As an aside, your `<label>`s are useless as they aren't associated with any controls. They need a `for` attribute with the same value as the `id` of the control they are to be associated with.

```
<form method="post" action="dothemath.php">

    <input type="radio" id="rdobuy" name="foo" value="buy" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="rdobuy">Buy</label>

    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="sell" id="rdosell" />
    <label for="rdosell">Sell</label>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a name attribute and the names should be same for both radios.

Answer (score 1):

you should add a name attribute to all your HTML element listed in your code. it helps the browser to identify what it sends to the server. Radios are optional based, you cant select two at a time, except you're using php arrays, simply use a check button instead for that.