# Why does my javascript prevent me from selecting a radio button more than once?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I would like to have a web donation form on my non-profit's website, and I would like people to be able to select a one-time gift or a monthly gift when they give via credit card. If they select a monthly gift, I would need to send some values to the payment processor, and a good way to do that seemed to be toggling the disabled attribute for the hidden form fields. I entered in two setAttribute() javascript functions for doing that, and two event listeners for clicking on the radio buttons. The problem is that adding those two functions and two listeners seems to have made it so that I can only click on the 'Monthly (Recurring) Gift' option once. The 'Single Gift' starts out checked, and if I then click on 'Monthly (Recurring) Gift' and then click on 'Single Gift', the browser won't let me select the 'Monthly (Recurring) Gift' option again. If I remove the javascript, it will let me do it. Why?

Here is my code with javascript:

```
    <form>

    <input type="hidden" name="OverRideRecureDay"
    id="overriderecureday"     value="Y" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="hidden" name="RID" id="rid" value="your_RID#"
    disabled="disabled">
    <input type="hidden" name="recur_times" id="recur_times"
    value="your_recur_times" disabled="disabled">

    <div id="giftfrequency">
    <div id="giftfrequencylabel" class="editor-label2">Gift Frequency:                       
    </div>

    <div class="editor-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="onetimedonation" name="override_recur"
    value="" checked="checked"></input> <span>Single Gift</span>

    </div>
    <div class="editor-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="recurringdonation" name="override_recur"
    value="Y"></input> <span>Monthly (Recurring) Gift</span>

    </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script>
      var MonthlyGift = document.getElementById("recurringdonation");
      var OneTimeGift = document.getElementById("onetimedonation");
      var OvrRecurDay = document.getElementById("overriderecureday");
      var RecurTimes = document.getElementById("recur_times");
      var RID = document.getElementById("rid");
      function EnableRecurring () {
        MonthlyGift.setAttribute("disabled", "");
        OvrRecurDay.setAttribute("disabled", "");
        RecurTimes.setAttribute("disabled","");
      };
      function DisableRecurring () {
        RID.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        OvrRecurDay.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        RecurTimes.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
      }; 
      document.getElementById("recurringdonation").addEventListener("click", EnableRecurring);
      document.getElementById("onetimedonation").addEventListener("click", DisableRecurring);
    </script>
```

JSFiddle for scenario with javascript is http://jsfiddle.net/s1011205/73zstxz0/1/

JSFiddle for scenario without javascript is http://jsfiddle.net/s1011205/5b47abz0/3/

I have looked elsewhere for a good answer but am not sure that I have been successful. A person was using Bootstrap in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056000/i-cant-switch-between-radio-button). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288350/cant-select-between-radio-buttons-in-html) does not apply because my two radio buttons do have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the radio button is being disabled when you click the Reoccurring radio button. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do in the Enable function. If you want intended to enable those elements, use this code below. If not, perhaps you did not realize the MonthlyGift is your Reoccuring radio button and you can correct that line. Either way, that is the issue.

```
function EnableRecurring() {
  MonthlyGift.removeAttribute("disabled");
  OvrRecurDay.removeAttribute("disabled");
  RecurTimes.removeAttribute("disabled");
};
```

Comment: Wow. You're right. I had "MonthlyGift.setAttribute("disabled", "")" in the EnableRecurring function where I should have had "RID.setAttribute("disabled", "")". That was my problem, and now the problem is solved. Thank you for catching my (self-generated) problem.

Comment: Sure thing! Just be sure that for those you use 'RID.removeAttribute("disabled");' if you are trying to enable (remove disabled) those elements.

Comment: Sam, do you mean to say that, in regard to what is passed to the server when one hits the form submit buttom, setAttribute("disabled", "") is not equivalent to removeAttribute("disabled")? I figured that setting the disabled attribute value to blank ("") would be sufficient. (I only started really learning coding to any significant extent when I started seriously into building the website for my non-profit in November (having no significant training or education in coding prior to then)).

Comment: Correct. You have to remove the disabled attribute to enable the element as both "" an "disabled" result in a disabled element. Alternatively, this is another way of doing it that you may like better. 
'RID.disabled = true' This is disabled. 'RID.disabled = false' This is enabled.

Comment: Here are the two working solutions you could choose from:
[.disabled JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lorpzgz/)
[.removeAttribute JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twsdrnLt/)

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I'll change my code. You may have saved me from charging donors on a monthly basis when they only would have wanted to give once (and if that is the case, HUGE thank you to you!!!).

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need JavaScript for this. The name attribute connects the radio buttons. If you need one to be enabled on page load then you can set that in the HTML. The user can then select one or the other from there.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>
```

Sourced from here.
[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Andre. The EnableRecurring and DisableRecurring functions were meant for the hidden form fields, not for the 'Monthly (Recurring) Gift' radio button. My error was that I had the "MonthlyGift.setAttribute("disabled", "")" in the EnableRecurring function where I should have had "RID.setAttribute("disabled", "")", and that might have encouraged you to think that I was trying to disable the Monthly gift radio button (when, in fact, I was not). On that supposition, you would be right, as the shared name would have been enough.